# editing(deleting,updating and editing) columns in a gridview using ASP.net framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, twitter-bootstrap, gridview

I'd like to edit my columns as I've said in the title. There are so many links about it but all of the include having back end codes in

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

However, I'm converting a bootstrap framework to ASP.net framework and I don't have any code in my `Page_Load` (yet).
The data is from a database table and before using a gridview,there is a SqlSource right there.
Here's my code:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" CssClass="table table-bordered table-
        striped" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID" OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound" 
        OnRowEditing="OnRowEditing"  OnRowCancelingEdit="OnRowCancelingEdit" 
OnRowUpdating="OnRowUpdating"  OnRowDeleting="OnRowDeleting" EmptyDataText="No records has been added.">            
    <columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="title" HeaderText="text1" SortExpression="title"  />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="text" HeaderText="text2" />
    </columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Now.I want to edit my columns ,as I've said before, what should I do? Do I have to have some code in `Page_Load()`? What should I do,let's say, if I want to delete a row?

Comment: The problem is here `I'm converting a bootstrap framework to ASP.net framework`. Asp.net is server side platform and not replacement of any UI manipulating framework

Comment: right now that's not a problem. Consider there's no bootstrap involved. Just need to delete a row of a gridview as I've said above.

Comment: are you using jqgrid or normal asp.net grid control??

Comment: What do you mean "edit my columns"? What specific edit you want to apply to your gridview?

Comment: @jomsk1e What should I do,let's say, if I want to delete a row?

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV normal asp.net grid

Comment: then use jqgrid it is more simpler and it allow all the features like edit add update and all.we can handle all in js .jqgrid is more usefull that asp.net gridview